# Don't know how to build task 'secret'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm building an api only rails application that uses devise for user authentication. I'm following [this](https://sdrmike.medium.com/rails-7-api-only-app-with-devise-and-jwt-for-authentication-1397211fb97c) guide and am on the step where I set up `devise-jwt`, and when I run `rake secret` I get the following:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'secret' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)
```

When I look for available tasks, `secret` is not one of them, but from what I can find on the internet, that's a task provided by rails out of the box.

Here's my Gemfile, if it's relevant (not including the gems that are commented out by default)

```
ruby "3.3.0"
gem "rails", "~> 7.1.2"
gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4"
gem "puma", ">= 5.0"
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ windows jruby ]
gem "bootsnap", require: false

gem "nokogiri"
gem "open-uri"
gem "devise"
gem "devise-jwt"
gem 'jsonapi-serializer'

group :development, :test do
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri windows ]
  gem "pry-byebug"
end

group :development do
  gem "annotate", git: 'https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models.git'
end
```

I do see that the secrets command is being deprecated in favor of `credentials`, however that is not one of my tasks either. According to the [rails documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#miscellaneous), the task should exist. What an I doing wrong? Was there a bad install of rails?

Troubleshooting:

```
$ rake secret
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'secret' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)

$ bundle exec rake -T | grep secret
(no output)

$ bundle exec rake -T                        
rake action_mailbox:ingress:exim        # Relay an inbound email from Exim to Actio...
rake action_mailbox:ingress:postfix     # Relay an inbound email from Postfix to Ac...
rake action_mailbox:ingress:qmail       # Relay an inbound email from Qmail to Acti...
rake action_mailbox:install             # Install Action Mailbox and its dependencies
rake action_mailbox:install:migrations  # Copy migrations from action_mailbox to ap...
rake action_text:install                # Copy over the migration, stylesheet, and ...
rake action_text:install:migrations     # Copy migrations from action_text to appli...
rake active_storage:install             # Copy over the migration needed to the app...
rake annotate_models                    # Add schema information (as comments) to m...
rake annotate_routes                    # Adds the route map to routes.rb
rake app:template                       # Apply the template supplied by LOCATION=(...
rake app:update                         # Update configs and some other initially g...
rake db:create                          # Create the database from DATABASE_URL or ...
rake db:drop                            # Drop the database from DATABASE_URL or co...
rake db:encryption:init                 # Generate a set of keys for configuring Ac...
rake db:environment:set                 # Set the environment value for the database
rake db:fixtures:load                   # Load fixtures into the current environmen...
rake db:migrate                         # Migrate the database (options: VERSION=x,...
rake db:migrate:down                    # Run the "down" for a given migration VERSION
rake db:migrate:redo                    # Roll back the database one migration and ...
rake db:migrate:status                  # Display status of migrations
rake db:migrate:up                      # Run the "up" for a given migration VERSION
rake db:prepare                         # Run setup if database does not exist, or ...
rake db:reset                           # Drop and recreate all databases from thei...
rake db:rollback                        # Roll the schema back to the previous vers...
rake db:schema:cache:clear              # Clear a db/schema_cache.yml file
rake db:schema:cache:dump               # Create a db/schema_cache.yml file
rake db:schema:dump                     # Create a database schema file (either db/...
rake db:schema:load                     # Load a database schema file (either db/sc...
rake db:seed                            # Load the seed data from db/seeds.rb
rake db:seed:replant                    # Truncate tables of each database for curr...
rake db:setup                           # Create all databases, load all schemas, a...
rake db:version                         # Retrieve the current schema version number
rake log:clear                          # Truncate all/specified *.log files in log...
rake remove_annotation                  # Remove schema information from model and ...
rake remove_routes                      # Removes the route map from routes.rb
rake stats                              # Report code statistics (KLOCs, etc) from ...
rake test                               # Run all tests in test folder except syste...
rake test:db                            # Reset the database and run `bin/rails test`
rake time:zones[country_or_offset]      # List all time zones, list by two-letter c...
rake tmp:clear                          # Clear cache, socket and screenshot files ...
rake tmp:create                         # Create tmp directories for cache, sockets...
rake yarn:install                       # Install all JavaScript dependencies as sp...
rake zeitwerk:check                     # Check project structure for Zeitwerk comp...
```

Followed rails [documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#miscellaneous)

Comment: you can use `rails secret` to generate a secret

Comment: In Rails 7.1+ you set the secret key base with `rails credentials:edit`. The gem may not be up to date with this best practice though.

Comment: Also use `bin/rails -t` to list the tasks. Don't quote me on this but rake may not pickup all the tasks.

Comment: @Thanh that worked, thanks! idk why it's not also a rake task when it previously was one

Answer (score 2):

It worked as `rails secret` instead of `rake secret`. Old documentation references the latter, but it must only be supported as the former in newer rails versions. I believe at one point they moved toward just using `rails` over `rake`. I'm just in the habit of using `rake` from the rails 4 days

Answer (score 1):

You should use `bin/rails` for everything:

```
bin/rails secret
```

Since `rails v5` you can run any `rake` task via `bin/rails`:

> Proxy Rake tasks through bin/rails. ([Pull Request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22457), [Pull Request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22288))

*https://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#railties-notable-changes*

`secret` is a rails command, not a rake task, you can't run it through rake. You can list all rake tasks with:

```bash
bin/rails -T

# which is the same as 
bin/rake -T
```

You can list all rails commands and rake tasks combined with:

```bash
bin/rails -h
```

---

Rails commands:
*https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/v7.1.3/railties/lib/rails/commands*

Rake tasks:
*https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/v7.1.3/railties/lib/rails/tasks*
*(tasks can also be loaded from other gems)*

Comment: Thanks! I was misled by the tutorial. I found one that is basically the same end-result that uses the right commands